# How do I get an HTML file to render in a React component?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have an HTML file (Home.html) with site info on it and would like to render that data via my Home.js component. I've been googling things but am not sure how to do it... I keep running into `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` and `<script>`.

Here is my code:

`Home.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Node.js upload images</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <style>
      div.preview-images > img {
        width: 30%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8 mt-3">
          <h4>Node.js upload images - bezkoder.com</h4>

          <form class="mt-4"
            action="/upload"
            method="POST"
            enctype="multipart/form-data"
          >
            <div class="form-group">
              <input
                type="file"
                name="file"
                id="input-files"
                class="form-control-file border"
              />
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr />
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="preview-images"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        let imagesPreview = function (input, placeToInsertImagePreview) {
            if (input.files) {
                let filesAmount = input.files.length;
                for (i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
                    let reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function (event) {
                        $($.parseHTML("<img>"))
                            .attr("src", event.target.result)
                            .appendTo(placeToInsertImagePreview);
                    };
                    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
                }
            }
        };
        $("#input-files").on("change", function () {
            imagesPreview(this, "div.preview-images");
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
```

`Home.js`

```
import React from "react";


const Home = () => (
  <div>
    <h1 className="title is-1">A Place to Document Things</h1>
    <p>
      Here, many things will be documented.
    </p>

    <div></div>
   
  </div>
);

export default Home;
```

I would like to render the `HTML` info in the `.js` file.
Thank you

Comment: Maybe through an iframe?

Comment: If you don't want to use an iframe, fetching the file content via ajax and then using dangerouslysetinnerhtml is the way to go.

Comment: why do you want to do this instead of creating a component which looks like the HTML document above?

Comment: @messerbill Thanks for this. I just did that--  found a HTML to JSX converter (https://magic.reactjs.net/htmltojsx.htm), and converted the file then used in component. Worked perfectly. Thank you

Comment: Just to add to all this, using `dangerouslySetInnerHtml` is a not a good practice. It can open your site up to a cross-site scripting (XSS) attack